# I am using a package for my language but not everything is translated

Tags: magento-1.7, localisation, language

I am using: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-core-modules-french-language-pack.html

for the translation of my website to french. But the bottom menu is in english for some reason.

[image]

Why? And what can I do to change this?

Comment: I think that comes from a static block named footer_links.

Comment: You're right for the first part but for the second part of the footer I cannot find where I can change it.

Comment: I am not sure but I think I need to modify the XML files for this. Here is a link that explains in detail:  http://www.magento.cc/how-to-edit-the-magento-footer-area.html

Comment: Is there a way to modify the language of these XML file but still have the advantage of multi-language?

Comment: yes, extend the original block so he puts the text trough ->__() so it uses the translate function

Comment: One is in a XML file... How the hell do translate that... The footer seems to be set by a XML file... The DB... It's very messy... Well I find.

Answer (score 3):

The language packages found on the magentocommerce.com website are not always complete. MOst of them are not.

The first row of footer links come from a static block called `footer_links`. You can edit that in `Cms->Static blocks`.

The second row comes from layout files. But the texts listed there should be available in the language files. You can search for a text in the files and translate it.

I can also recommend [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool) for working with translations.
Here is what it does:

- collect texts from specified modules and generates a csv file for
  each module.
- identifies the texts from a specified locale that have the same
  translation as the key: "Customer","Customer". Note: False positives
  may occur.
- generates all the locale files for the selected modules in a specific
  language, by collecting the texts from the module files and merging
  with the already existing locale files.

Just make sure you backup your language files before using the extension...just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Every Magento update "breaks" language package, creating tons of updated strings which while being similar to old ones have different capitalization, punctuation and whatnot. reason being that third party package maintainers are often several versions behind in the release schedule.

In your case, you also overlooked static blocks.